# Extract multiple data from cell in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, vba

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvlnO.png)I need to extract three variables from a single cell. I have been able to use regexp to extract the first 4 numbers. Now I would also like to extract the next four digits (1970) What do I need to add to get that?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

```
Function getZip(addr As String)

Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = "(\d{4})"
RE.Global = True
RE.IgnoreCase = True

Set allMatches = RE.Execute(addr)

If (allMatches.Count <> 0) Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
End If

getZip = result

End Function
```

Comment: What do you expect to get as a result? A collection? Or do you just want to know how to iterate through the matches?

Comment: I want to return the 3 highlighted variables on the picture to 3 individual cells. The VBA I posted allowed me to extract 5260 because the script looks for 4 digits. But I have 2 variables with 4 digits.

Comment: Sorry, I think we need more details then.

Comment: The VBA I posted allowed me to extract 5260 to individual cell. I also want to extract 1970. How do I do that

Comment: Is all of the above in a single cell? Are the lines supposed to indicate different rows? Please provide data in an appropriate format rather than as an image. Also, please give an expected output example. Are you planning on extracting 1970, 1895 and 1935? And then what are you going to do with those numbers? As per @WiktorStribiżew's comment.

Comment: Well, the basic issue here is that you only access 1 match, you'd need to use `For Each match1 In allMatches //  coll.Add match1.Value  // Next` to iterate through all of them. Next, what if you have numbers like `1234560000`? I think you need `\b\d{4}\b` regex.

Comment: On the picture you will see 3 factors highlighted. each factor, I want to simply copy to 3 individual cells (each factor gets its own cell) Assuming A1 is the cell with all the data. Then A2 should be first highlighted factor, A3 second highlighted factor, A4 third highlighted factor. I added a better picture for more clarification.

Comment: you need a pattern for each factor and then search for each factor individually

Comment: I see 3 four-digit numbers, not 2.  Also, yo additional image didn't provide any additional clarification...  Does the position of the data *vary* or will the parts you need **always** be in the same place in the cells?  For example, *is it always **"the 2nd line" and "the number at the end of the 9th line"*** that you need?  If so, that makes it easy.  If not, more information and examples of different possibilities are necessary.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 four-digits numbers (1 with a DOT as a separator and the other two WITHOUT) All the data is always like this so 2nd and 9th line.

Comment: I suggest 3 patterns like [first 4 digit number](https://regex101.com/r/zm6Tzz/1), [place name](https://regex101.com/r/GLqRMH/1) and [bygget i](https://regex101.com/r/6sp4M8/1). Catch the first submatch of each and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add 3 patterns and a parameter `PatternNo` to choose which pattern to use:

```
Function getZip(addr As String, PatternNo As Long)       
    Dim allMatches As Object
    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim Patterns As Variant 'define 3 patterns 0 to 2
    Patterns = Array("([0-9]{4}) .*", "[0-9]{4} (.*)", "bygget i ([0-9]{4})")

    'you might want to add an error handling here (see end of this answer)

    RE.Pattern = Patterns(PatternNo) 'choose pattern by its number
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True

    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(addr)
    If (allMatches.Count <> 0) Then
        result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
    End If

    getZip = result   
End Function
```

I suggest these patterns:

- first 4 digit number: `([0-9]{4}) .*` https://regex101.com/r/zm6Tzz/1
- place name: `[0-9]{4} (.*)` https://regex101.com/r/GLqRMH/1
- bygget i: `bygget i ([0-9]{4})` https://regex101.com/r/6sp4M8/1

It is probably a good idea to check that the `PatternNo` does not exceed the number of patterns in the array `Patterns` and return an error if it does:

```
If PatternNo < 0 Or PatternNo > UBound(Patterns) Then
    getZip = 'return your desired error here
    Exit Function
End If
```

Also you might want to return an error if no match was found at all.